# Concatenate two dataframes (vertically) with different number of columns

Tags: python, pandas

What is the simplest way to concatenate two dataframes with some columns matching and some missing in one of them?

Eg.

df_1

[image]

df_2

[image]

**wanted:**

[image]

Thank you for any help :)

Comment: Did you try `pd.concat((df1,df2), axis=1)`?

Comment: `pd.concat([df1,df2],sort=False)` or `df1.append(df2,sort=False)`

Comment: @ Quang Hoang, this was the first option I've tried, but with axis=0 however, it re-orded columns in alphabetical order

Comment: @anky_91, it works. just need to chek it for the original data if it places data in a right column Thank you!